# Is there a string formatter that will use the same syntax as SLF4J?

Tags: java, logging, formatting, slf4j

I am (obviously) familiar with both `String.format()` and `MessageText.format()` - I also understand the string formatting syntax used in `Slf4j` logging; it is frustrating that they are all different and incompatible.

What I am looking for is a `MessageText.format()` -like function, that works exactly as the slf4j loggers' formatters, so I can use the same String constants both in log messages and in (for example) exception messages:

```java
public static String THIS_HAPPENED = 
        "Unfortunately, foo was {}, but bar ({}) was not";

// ...

if (someDisaster(foo, bar)) {
    log.error(THIS_HAPPENED, foo, bar);
    throw new IllegalStateException(MessageText.betterFormat(THIS_HAPPENED,
                                                                 foo, bar));
}
```

Unfortunately, `MessageText` needs the position specifier (`{0}`) and Slf4j positively hates it.

Is there something out there that does this?

(Obviously, obviously!, I can write the method myself, but if it's already been done by coders better than I, I would happily use that instead).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to:

```
import org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter;
```

there you have:

```
MessageFormatter.format(messagePattern, arg).getMessage();
```

Comment: Thanks! For others stumbling on the same question, just noting to add `getMessage()` (and not `toString()`) as the `format()` method returns a "tuple" and not a `String`.